# Mounting nix VM Guest Filesystem from Host with Dokan and WIn SSHFS

Tags: virtual-machine, sshfs

Works fine for remote machines.

Is it possible to sshfs to linux guest vm from win host with dokan and winsshfs?

Tried on vw11 and vbox5 with no success. No problems sticking with current setup (shared folder), just integration with win explorer would play nice nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

Shared folder? sshfs is a fuse/dokan filesystem to access remote files via the ssh protocol, no matter of real or virtual. If you have the guest filesystem mounted as shared folder, you have already access to the files. What do you want with a additional sshfs?

Comment: A shared folder is on host, mounted in vm guest, we want the other way, to mount/map the vm guest filesystem on host machine within windows explorer while guest is running. Dokan works fine across physical network, not working for guest vm stored on host machine. It's trivial as there are many other ways to do it. Just I don't see why Dokan and win sshfs not working for local vm guests.

Comment: Okay, do you know the virtual machine network and the address of the VM? It is bridged, NAT or host only? Answers the VM onto ping request? Is the sshd of the VM listening on this address? Try to connect with WinSCP to the VM? If not, what ist the result of ``tcpdump -i xxx port ssh``? Where xxx is the interface name of the external interface of the VM.

Comment: its NAT, everything works fine, no firewalls etc ping of course works, I believe it has something to do with how Dokan hooks into stack, it must do something differently as all other tools don't care if local or remote, just Dokan or winsshfs (not that I'm packet sniffing so haven't dug real deep). Don't bust your head over it, I'm just flabbergasted that it didn't work. I'm not that into `C` to check source, its just why it doesn't work that eats at me, if you know what I mean.